# Why Vue doesn't show data from my WebApi with axios and params?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vue.js, axios

i am practicing with axios and Vue in the use of WebApi.

I have done this:

**My template:**

```
  <template>
<form>
    <div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h1><strong>Lista de nombres</strong></h1></div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                            <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr v-for="usuario in usuarios">
                            <td>{{usuario.Nombre}}</td>
                            <td>{{usuario.Apellido_P}}</td>
                            <td>{{usuario.Apellido_M}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <p>Buscar usuario</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar usuario" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="buscarUsuario">Buscar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
</template>
```

**And My Script:**

```
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                usuarios:[],
                busqueda: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            buscarUsuario() {
                axios.get('http://localhost:50995/api/GetUsuario', {
                    params: {
                        'id' : 7
                    }
                }).then(response => {
                    this.usuarios = response.data
                    }).catch(e => {
                        console.log(e)
                    })
            },

            getUsuarios() {
                axios.get("http://localhost:50995/api/GetUsuarios")
                    .then(response => {
                        this.usuarios = response.data
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })

            }
        },

        created() {
                this.getUsuarios(),
                this.buscarUsuario()
        }


    }

</script>
```

The method getUsuarios() is working well; but the method buscarUsuario() not; only if i put in the params ‘id’ a number the log of my WebApi records a query, but if write this code: `this.busqueda` not working. Either way, the result in the page is not working with the method buscarUsuario().

And finally friends, how to prevent load the page everytime i push the button?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems kind of strange. I conclude you reading it properly on server-side. So I bet your server only wants Number(7) not String(7). You should change basic stance of **busqueda** to null. Then add .number modifier to v-model. Like that:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model.number="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar usuario" />
```

**How to prevent load the page everytime you push button?**
*Add .prevent modifier.*
Change:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="buscarUsuario">Buscar</button>
```

To:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click.prevent="buscarUsuario">Buscar</button>
```

Also I recomend use @ as shortcut for v-on:(in this example you could have use @click.prevent).

*If it still refreshes. Add @submit.prevent="functionName" to form...*

Answer (score 0):

Use id without quote and click.prevent to prevent submit.

```js
params: {
  id: 7
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click.prevent="buscarUsuario">Buscar</button>
```

also you can use button type="buttton"

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="buscarUsuario">Buscar</button>
```